# lists and for loop syntax

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

so I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to build a python program to print the Fibonacci sequence.
my code is as follows:

```
fib_sequence = [0,1,1]

def fib_add(x):
   fib_seq.insert(x, int(fibseq[x-1]+fibseq[x-2])

for n in range(2,10):
   fib_add(n)
   print(fib_seq)
```

the program says there is a syntax error at the colon on

```
for n in range(2,10):
```

I don't know how to correct it

Comment: Adding the exact error log would help as it does not looks incorrect. Although looks like a closing brace missing near `int(fibseq[x-1]+fibseq[x-2])`

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, that is *not* where the syntax error is. It is the preceding line that is the problem:

```
   fib_seq.insert(x, int(fibseq[x-1]+fibseq[x-2]))
```

This line was missing closing parentheses. What happens in such cases is that, since the parentheses were not closed, the Python interpreter continues looking for more stuff to put in the expression. It hits the `for` in the next line and continues all the way to right before the colon. At this point, there is a way to continue the code which is still valid.

*Then*, it hits the colon. There is no valid Python syntax which allows a colon there, so it stops and raises an error at the first token which is objectively in the wrong place. In terms of your intention, however, we can see that the mistake was actually made earlier.

Also, as noted in a comment, your original `list` was named `fib_sequence`, while in the rest of your code you reference `fib_list`. This will raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your for loop code inside main. Also as the other answer suggests, you must add another parenthesis after

```
fib_seq.insert(x, int(fibseq[x-1]+fibseq[x-2]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   for n in range(2,10):
   fib_add(n)
   print(fib_seq)
```

Comment: I think there is actually no need to do so, since this code is being run only as a script, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
fib_seq = [0,1,1]

def fib_add(x):
   fib_seq.insert(x, int(fib_seq[x-1]+fib_seq[x-2]))

for n in range(3,10):
   fib_add(n)
   print(fib_seq)
```

Resulting Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you have some useful answers, you might look into generators, they make `Python` a powerful language:

```
def fibonacci():
    x, y = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield x
        x, y = y, x + y

for x in fibonacci():
    if x >= 10:
        break
    print(x)
```

This prints

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
```